# Print lines between two patterns that contain multiple asterix

Tags: awk

Input file:

```
$ cat my.txt

dsfsdf

sdfsdf

*** abc (>2% kmn rto >0.2% sdf) ***

123

234

678

asdf

asdasd

*** xyz 4 gho ***

asdasd

asdasd

asdasd

asdasd
```

From `my.txt` I need to print the content between these two lines `*** abc (>2% kmn rto >0.2% sdf) ***` and `*** xyz 4 gho ***` which is :

```
123

234

678

asdf

asdasd
```

I am getting this error:

```
$ awk '/*** abc (>2% kmn rto >0.2% sdf) ***/{ f = 1; next } /*** xyz 4 gho ***/{ f = 0 } f' my.txt >> my_new.txt
awk: illegal primary in regular expression
```

Please help

Comment: Try escaping `(` and `)` in regular expressions. e.g. `/*** abc \(>2% kmn rto >0.2% sdf\) ***/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary issue is the parens in the start pattern being treated as special regex characters (as Andre commented: escape the parens).  The end pattern works as expected.

A couple other ideas that short circuit `awk's` attempt to interpret the pattern contents as special characters:

```
# if you know the entire line is a match:

awk '$0 == "*** abc (>2% kmn rto >0.2% sdf) ***" {f=1; next} $0 == "*** xyz 4 gho ***" {f=0} f' my.txt

# feed pattern to index()

$ awk 'index($0,"*** abc (>2% kmn rto >0.2% sdf) ***") {f=1; next} index($0,"*** xyz 4 gho ***") {f=0} f' my.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
123

234

678

asdf

asdasd
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```bash
awk '/^\*\*\*/ {in_range = 1 - in_range; next}; in_range' my.txt
```

- The `/^\*\*\*/ {in_range = 1 - in_range; next}` part said: If we encounter the *** pattern, toggle `in_range` from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0
- The `in_range` part will print the text

Comment: Instead of escaping a bunch of characters to make a regexp comparison act as if it was a string comparison, just do a string comparison `index($0,"***") == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tricky one:

```bash
sed -n '/^\*\*\*.*\*\*\*$/,// {//! p}' my.txt
```

This takes advantage of sed's use of the empty regex to reuse the *previous* regex.

- `/^\*\*\*.*\*\*\*$/,//` -- the range of lines starting from matching a line that begins and ends with 3 asterisks to a similar line
- `{//! p}` -- print the line if it does **not** match the same pattern